# Using my own HTML5 data attributes in a Rails link_to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

I have a link_to helper that I'd love to use Twitter's Bootstrap.js to provide a popover. I have the following code:

"access", :action => "login" %>

I need to add the following HTML attributes: data-placement="" and rel="".

How do I do this using link_to? I've tried different variations of this:

```
<%= link_to "Login", 'data-placement' => 'below', :controller => "access", :action => "login" %>

<%= link_to "Login", html_options = {'data-placement' => 'below'}, :controller => "access", :action => "login" %>

<%= link_to "Login", :data => {'placement' => 'below'}, :controller => "access", :action => "login" %>
```

All these do is append things to my URL so it becomes:

http://localhost:3000/access/login?data-placement=below

I'm sure I've done this before!

-Jim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently when using this format, I needed to specify the controller and action in a hash.

```
<%= link_to "Login", {:controller => "access", :action => "login"}, 'data-placement' => 'below' %>
```

Comment: <%= link_to "Login", {:controller => "access", :action => "login"}, :data =>  {'placement' => 'below'} %>